# How do I change the background image of a UICollectionViewCell that has been tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have multiple `UICollectionViewCells`. When the user taps on a specific cell, I would like my app to change the background image of the touched cell.

My approach is to focus on the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method. When a cell is touched, this method will be called.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))
}
```

However, I can't get it working but I don't know why. The issue is probably related to `indexPath`, that doesn't return a correct value of the cell. I tried using `indexPath.row` and this does actually return an `Int` number of the cell.

What's more, I'm also creating a new `UICollectionViewCell` with `var` but this cell already exists.

Why isn't the cell updating its background image? How do I change the background image of a `UICollectionViewCell` that has been touched by the user?

Comment: Could you use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to get the cell instead of dequeuing another one?

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is a method used to place the cells inside a `UICollectionView`. It doesn't get called when you select a cell.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as a method to get the cell. Not totally sure on swift syntax but `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally agree with the Josh's answer, but if you change the background image using the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method it works fine as well. Then, you can use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that returns the `UITableViewCell` at the specified `indexPath`, like in the following way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "photo2"))        
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "photo1"))
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    return cell
}
```

I just put the `selectionStyle` to `.None` to avoid the highlight. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you Victor. I'm not using a `UITableView`, but a `UICollectionView`. You may want to replace `tableView` with `collectionView`. Also, does the `selectionStyle` property work in `UICollectionViews`?

Comment: @JoshGafni Yes, you're right but I don't answer any of you say, and the question was not about the reusable cell or anything else, I only answer a specific case.

Comment: Please see the first sentence of my answer